# How to avoid overlapping SVG icons and labels?

Tags: qgis, point-of-interest

I've dropped a point and then selected a SVG icon. But now I'm right next to the other points I want to label. Now you have the SVG icon, but be on the label, that is, the label may no longer be seen.

Is this a default setting that you can change?

Comment: when you say dropped a point do you mean created a point?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of choices here, depending upon what is exactly happening (which I don't clearly understand from your description).

If you are using the advanced labeling toolbar, you can data-define your label's location (using x, y fields in attribute table) and use the Move Label tool to manually position the label.

See [linfiniti.com blog for info on using the new labeling toolbar](http://linfiniti.com/2011/03/interactive-label-placement-in-qgis-1-7/).

If the label is not visible, because the new feature point has a higher priority, check the *Show All Labels (i.e. including colliding labels)* choice in the Engine Settings dialog of advanced labeling.

[image]

This will show the label, even if it overlaps something else, like another label or a feature.

Alternatively, if your points are overlapping, you may want to check out the [Shift Points plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/shiftpoints/), if you want to create a new shapefile with the points offset.

> "Moves overlapped points in a circle around original position."